# Multi-Column Global Navigation Drop Down Menu for SharePoint 2010

Tags: jquery, css, sharepoint-2010, navigation

I was wondering if it were at all possible (ideally using just CSS and/or jQuery) to create a multi-column drop-down navigation menu in SharePoint 2010. I am referencing a sitemap for my global navigation within our SharePoint environment and have one menu that stretches for well over 20 links. This causes an issue on lower-resolution screens. We want to be able to wrap this long list over into two columns (and ideally have a container in place on the other menu items where if their child links reach a certain number, a second column expands the container and is created as well).

Is this something that can be done with CSS and/or jQuery? Some resources I have found mention the use of a custom navigation control, but I would like to think that this can be more easily done. I found this link for SP2007 (http://tothepoint.inproc.com/creating-mega-drop-down-navigation-in-sharepoint-2007-with-jquery/ ), but I'm looking for something a little more simple. Any ideas how this can be done?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding following classes to your custom css file or master page . This solution is working for us. This will give you 2 column layout .

```
.menu UL.dynamic
{
    width:500px !important;
}
.dynamic
{
    display:inline-block;float:left;min-width:250px;
}
```

For 3 column layout use classes given below, you can adjust width and min-width as per your needs

```
.menu UL.dynamic
{
    width:600px !important;
}
.dynamic
{
    display:inline-block;float:left;min-width:200px;
}
```